# How many name prefixes can be stacked onto one weapon?

Tags: team-fortress-2

A lot of weapons aren't just your standard weapon. Certain 'Qualities' can be applied to make them stand out or increase their rarity.

For example, Strange weapons count kills (or otherwise weapon-related points), and they are seen as 'Strange <Weapon>' (or a variant thereof) in-game.

However I see a lot of weapons going around with names like ***Spectacularly Lethal Specialised Killstreak Festive Knife***, and I was wondering: What's the **maximum** amount of name prefixes that can be stacked onto a singular weapon? Are there certain item/killstreak/quality prefixes which are incompatible with others?

Comment: 'Spectacularly Lethal' == strange.

Comment: @ColinD - I know :) Just an example

Comment: Don't forget [Strange Filters](https://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Strange_Filter), which add a unique prefix to a Strange weapon indicating the map it is restricted to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To start with, *Strange* and *Killstreak* can be applied to almost any weapon (of any quality). Both of which could add up to two words to the name.

The following qualities do not interact at all:

1. Vintage
2. Community
3. Self-made
4. Australium
5. Festive
6. Genuine

Some other qualities exist like *Unusual* & *Haunted*, but they apply mostly to cosmetics and some special weapons such as the [Horseless Headless Horsemann's Headtaker](https://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Horseless_Headless_Horsemann's_Headtaker).

You can add *Collectors* to both *Festive* and *Vintage* (not sure about the others because how rare they are).

You can also add '*Strange Filters*' to items which will add an additional prefix word based on the map that you are filtering.

Example for longest weapon prefix:

> Hale's Own Frosty Professional Killstreak Collectors (Festive/Vintage) WEAPON

---

**Update:** I have no idea how all of this fits in with the new 'Decorated' weapons released with the 2015 Gunmettle update.

Comment: Are Australium and Festive technically "qualities", considering that the items they apply to are distinct items from their regular variants (i.e. an Aussie Grenade Launcher is as distinct from a Grenade Launcher as it is from a Flame Thrower)?

Comment: Vintage *is* a proper quality, and both it and Collector's will appear before the Killstreak prefix, not after it (although I'm not sure that it is possible to have an item that is both Vintage and Collector's yet), and after the Strange prefix. Examples: Strange Vintage Stockbroker's Scarf, Vintage Killstreak Half-Zatoichi, Strange Collector's Killstreak Phlogistinator.

Comment: You forgot the fact that you could also add Strange Filters to an item which lock them to only counting stats from a specific map. That will also add an extra prefix depending on which map you lock it to.

Comment: @Texenox Frosty is the Strange Filter name for Coldfront (or so I'm assuming).

Comment: Having said that, Collectors is another quality that doesn't interact with one another.  The longest current one is going to be Unusual Hale's Own [Strange Filter] [Professional/Specialized] Killstreak [Decorated Item]... because Unusual weapons are a thing for [Decorated](https://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Decorated) weapons.

Comment: @Powerlord Collectors does interact with other:  http://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/440/Strange%20Collector%27s%20Professional%20Killstreak%20Righteous%20Bison

Comment: @Colin Strange and Killstreaks aren't on the list of qualities that don't interact.  Having said that, Strange only mixes for items that have Strangifiers rather than just Strange versions... [such as the Righteous Bison](http://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/440/Righteous%20Bison%20Strangifier).

Comment: As of the Christmas 2015 update, Decorated weapons can now be turned into Festive weapons, so you can now have `Unusual Strange Festive` items.  i.e. `Unusual Hale's Own Frosty Professional Killstreak Festive WEAPON`, but that's not really longer than before as you can't have Collectors versions of them.